# Can some please help me?

Tags: soft-question, algorithms, math-software, python

Why I am getting nan in python.

```
from sympy import *
x,f,g=symbols('x f g')

def f(x):
    return (1+x**2)**2
def g(x):
    return (1-f(x))/x
expand(g(x))
g(0)
```

I know the $x$ is in division but after manual simplification I found $$g(x)=−^3−2$$ and $$g(0)=0$$
I could not understand why python result give me $$g(0) = NaN$$ How can I get g(0)=0 in python.

Comment: Computers are dumb and they do exactly what you tell them to do. Python is not smart enough to algebraically simplify $g(x)$ before evaluating $g(0)$. When Python evaluates $g(x)$, Python simply evaluates $1 - f(x)$ and then divides the result by $x$. So the code is dividing by $0$, resulting in a NaN.

Comment: Even if $g(x)=\frac{1-f(x)}x$ were to simplify to $-x^3-2x$, I would still say that $x$ is not in the domain of $g$ as it is currently written.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround:

```
from sympy import *
x,f,g,t=symbols('x f g t')

def f(x):
    return (1+x**2)**2
def g(x):
    return expand((1-f(t))/t).subs(t,x)
print(g(0))
```